# Redirect to parent iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iframe

I have one iframe that holds 4 menu tabs. On 1st menu tab, on the click of link button i wish to redirect to second menu tab of iframe.

The iframe is included in one of the content page of the master page. FYI, i am using an update panel on gridview (where link button is one of the template field)

My Question: How to redirect to parent iframe (that too second tab)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location.href = top.location.href;
```

That will set the current frame to its parent's url

Comment: if you want to redirect with a link it would be '<a href="javascript:location.href = top.location.href">Redirect</a>' or if you want to just redirect the page when it loads it would be `<script type="text/javascript">location.href = top.location.href</script>`